# En c# Como saber que boton ejecuto una función si varios tienen la misma funcion en el metodo OnClick?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Tengo varios botones con diferente nombre y uId pero todos con el mismo método en el evento `OnClick`.

¿Como podría saber el nombre o el uId del botón que ejecuto la función desde su evento?

Estos son mis botones:

```xml
<ToggleButton
   x:Name="PZ18PGMD1B_1"
   Click="drawSensor_Click">
</ToggleButton>

<ToggleButton
   x:Name="PZ19XYZ_2"
   Click="drawSensor_Click">
</ToggleButton>

<ToggleButton
   x:Name="PA19XYZ_3"
   Click="drawSensor_Click">
</ToggleButton>
```

Y este es el metodo que todos ejecutan:

```cs
    private void drawPiezometer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            MessageBox.Show(clickedButton.Name); 
        }
```

Intente hacer el **cast** del objeto `sender` a uno button pero no ha sido posible, de que manera podría conocer el nombre del botón que ha disparado el evento?

Comment: Pon algo de código en la pregunta para poder responderte. El evento OnClick y los botones.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con tus sugerencias, muchas gracias.

Comment: Con que framework estas trabajando? Xamarin forms?

Comment: Para el WPF y estilos el de MaterialDesign (He quitado esto del axml para no hacer tan abundante el codigo) la parte logica c# puro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes hacer el **Cast** con la clase correspondiente al `<ToggleButton />` --> [ToggleButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=netframework-4.8)

Prueba de esta manera:

```
    private void drawPiezometer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton clickedButton = sender as ToggleButton;
        MessageBox.Show(clickedButton.Name); 
    }
```

Comment: Ha funcionado, muchas gracias.